# Array accesses and basic operations

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

I was looking through some lecture slides on algorithm analysis and found that in general an array access counted as a basic operation, but it did not seem to count as one when accessing the first element (e.g. `A[i]` is a basic operation but `A[0]` isn't). Does only accessing the first element count as a basic operation, and if it doesn't, does accessing  an array by a predefined index (e.g. `A[5]`) count as one, and why is this the case?

Comment: In regards to the lecture notes, I would imagine they mean `A[5]` takes 1 basic operation because it's essentially getting the memory address of `A` the adding `5` memory units (depending on what `A` contains). The addition would be the basic operation, whereas `A[0]` requires no addition to `A`. Usually the compiler will optimize these scenarios and, as David said, they're both essentially one step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually doesn't matter, since we're usually only interested in the order of growth of the number of steps.  As long as we both agree that evaluating `A[i]` is a constant number of steps, independent of `i`, it doesn't actually matter what that constant is and we don't need to agree that it's the same constant.  We'll both agree that the algorithm is, say, $\Theta(n^2)$, even if I think the running time is $45n^2 + 16n + 18$ and you think it's $68n^2+25n+21$.  (And, in reality, neither of us is likely to be able to evaluate the running time to that level of precision.

So, it's usually fine to say that `A[0]` is a single step, as is `A[5]` (any sane compiler would compute "five cells beyond `A[0]`" at compile-time anyway) and `A[i]` where `i` is some variable. It won't make any difference to most analyses if you say that `A[5]` and `A[i]` are two operations due to having to compute the offset.

In some models of computation, things might be a bit more complicated because, if `i` is an arbitrary integer, it might not be sensible to assume that you can manipulate it in a constant number of steps. For example, on a standard Turing machine, you need to  read $\log\texttt{i}$ tape cells just to know what `i` is. But that doesn't look much like what a real computer does.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! I'll email the lecturer just to make sure what he wants for the exam, but that's a great answer when it comes to the real world.